# Change file permissions in java

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to convert the `MultipartFile` to `File` and upload this to specified directory on my `ec2` instance. Here is the converter method.

```kotlin
 private fun convertMultiPartFileToFile(multipartFile: MultipartFile, name: String): File? {
        val file = multipartFile.originalFilename?.let { File(it) }
        try {
            log.info { file?.canWrite() } // logs 'false'
            log.info { file?.canExecute() } // logs 'false'
            file?.setExecutable(true) // still 'false'
            file?.setWritable(true) // still 'false'

            file.let {
                if (file != null) {
                    FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream -> outputStream.write(multipartFile.bytes) }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

        return file
    }
```

It works locally, but when I try this on my `ec2` instance, I got the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.png (Permission denied)
```

I guess it's because I do not have permission to write to specified file. How can I solve this if `file?.setWritable(file)` and `file?.setExecutable(true)` return false.
I run the jar by `java -jar path/to/jar`

The `setWritable` method documentation says

```
     * @return  {@code true} if and only if the operation succeeded.  The
     * operation will fail if the user does not have permission to
     * change the access permissions of this abstract pathname.
```

How to get the access permissions to this abstract pathname then?

Comment: *Usually* when you don't have permission to write to a file you also don't have permission to just set it to writeable (there are exceptions, but they are unusual).  It seems you just create a `File` instance without any directory part, just a name, i.e. write it to the current directory. That's unlikely to work in a Linux system. You might need to put those writes into a temporary directory, maybe by simply using `File.createTempFile`. If you have a specific target directory in mind, then it's better to make sure it's writeable *before you code runs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultipartFile`s do not represent files on the file system while `File` represents a local file on your system. They are just data that's uploaded.

Hence, `multipartFile.originalFilename` does not give you the name of any file on your system (except a file with the same name "randomly" exists) but the name of the file the user uploaded (on their system).

If you want to access a `MultipartFile` as a `File`, you first need to save it as such:

```kotlin
val file=File("what/ever/file/you.want")//in the directory you want to upload it to
multipartFile.transferTo(file)
//it is now stored in file
```

This will copy the file to your system.